# Google Maps API v3 - Display Image capture date in StreetView

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

When you visit maps.google.com there is an information at the right bottom corner saying when the image has been captured:
[screenshot google maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFOrw.jpg)

However on my site when I use Google Maps API, that information is simply not shown. I cannot find any setting for this either.
Does anyone know how to display that information?

*EDIT:
I don't use google.maps.StreetViewPanorama, but google.maps.Map where the user can switch to StreetView mode.*

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to set the options by getting the StreetView object from the map:

```
this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.divContainer, defaultMapOptions);
this.map.getStreetView().setOptions(defaultStreetViewOptions);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to your original question. The other [not accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41381177/1238965) does, though.

Answer (score 3):

When you create the Street View, specify the `imageDateControl` attribute in the options.  It's disabled by default; you have to enable it.

Something like:

```js
var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
  document.getElementById('pano'), {
    position: yourLocation,
    imageDateControl: true
  });
```

See:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#StreetViewPanoramaOptions

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One thing was not clear enough in my question: I don't create a StreetViewPanorama, but i create a google.maps.Map. On that map a user can switch to StreetView mode. I was not able to set the imageDateControl-option on the map-options.

Comment: Sorry, my misunderstanding. I'm not sure you can set an option to make this appear.